# How to display data from today's date and month to the next 3 months only in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

So, I have employee contract data that will expire, I want to display the employee data for today's month and date for the next 3 months. I've tried using DATEADD or DATE_ADD but it still doesn't work. Please help

This is my query:

```
SELECT a.fullname, a.employee_id, a.id_number, b.date_contract_from, b.date_contract_to AS expired,                                                                           
       b.is_current, b.is_deleted, b.employment_status 
FROM hr_employees a
INNER JOIN hr_employee_jobs b
ON a.id = b.employee                                                     
WHERE b.date_contract_to >= NOW()
AND b.employment_status IN ('1', '2')
AND b.is_current = 1
AND b.is_deleted = 0  AND a.is_deleted = 0
GROUP BY b.employee
ORDER BY b.date_contract_to ASC
```

This is an example of how it looks. So, the expiry date in April should not appear.

[this is the query view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCXN3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use date [between](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) in your Query and [DATE_ADD](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_add.asp) function like this.

```
SELECT a.fullname, a.employee_id, a.id_number, b.date_contract_from, b.date_contract_to AS expired,                                                                           
       b.is_current, b.is_deleted, b.employment_status 
FROM hr_employees a
INNER JOIN hr_employee_jobs b
ON a.id = b.employee                                                     
WHERE b.date_contract_to BETWEEN now() AND  DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
AND b.employment_status IN ('1', '2')
AND b.is_current = 1
AND b.is_deleted = 0  AND a.is_deleted = 0
GROUP BY b.employee
ORDER BY b.date_contract_to ASC
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it worked!!! thanksss